# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [abc] associated with context path [APP_NAME]

Tags: struts2, annotations, struts2-convention-plugin, action-mapping

I am getting this issue when using Annotations in my Struts2 code.

My Annotated Action class seems something like this which is using interceptors, and my architecture is based on Spring 3, Struts 2, and using Struts2 Convention Plugin

```
@InterceptorRefs({  
    @InterceptorRef("mylogging")  
}) 
public class LoginAction  implements ModelDriven{
    User user = new User();
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    UserBo userBo;
    @Action(value="/login",results={@Result(name="success",type="chain",location="/jsp/successPage.jsp"),
            @Result(name="login",type="chain",location="/jsp/userLogin.jsp")})
    public String execute() {
        if(user.getUserScreenName()==null)
            return "login";
        System.out.println(userBo.verifyUser(user));
        return "success";
    }
```

I am also trying to enclose the details of my deployment descriptor

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param> <param-name>config</param-name> <param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,struts.xml
</param-value>
            </init-param>
      </filter>


      <filter-mapping>

        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
      <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/resources/config/SpringBeans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

       <listener>
        <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>

      </listener>
```

I have defined my interceptor in `struts.xml` which I am just using for defining interceptors and result types

```
   <struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
     <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
     <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="com.abc.lab"/>
     <constant name="struts.convention.action.checkImplementsAction" value="false"/>
      <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="action,actions,struts,struts2"/> <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
     <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="mylogging" 
                class="com.abc.lab.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor">
            </interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="loggingStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="mylogging" />

                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />    
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors> </package> </struts>
```

I have also tried with `devMode` true or false but it wasn't helpful.

My directory structure is

```
+--LmsWar/
|  +--pom.xml
|  +--src/
|  |  +--com/
|  |  |  +--abc/
|  |  |  |  +--lab/
|  |  |  |  |  +--actions/
|  |  |  |  |  |  +--HomeAction.java
|  |  |  |  |  |  +--LoginAction.java
|  |  |  |  |  +--bo/
|  |  |  |  |  |  +--impl/
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  +--UserBoImpl.java
|  |  |  |  |  |  +--UserBo.java
|  |  |  |  |  +--dao/
|  |  |  |  |  |  +--impl/
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  +--UserDAOImpl.java
|  |  |  |  |  |  +--UserDAO.java
|  |  |  |  |  +--filter/
|  |  |  |  |  +--interceptor/
|  |  |  |  |  |  +--LoggingInterceptor.java
|  |  |  |  |  +--listener/
|  |  |  |  |  +--model/
|  |  +--resources/
|  |  |  +--com/
|  |  |  |  +--abc/
|  |  |  |  |  +--lab/
|  |  |  |  |  |  +--spring/
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  +--UserBean.xml
|  |  |  +--config/
|  |  |  |  +--database/
|  |  |  |  |  +--properties/
|  |  |  |  |  |  +--database.properties
|  |  |  |  +--spring/
|  |  |  |  |  +--DataSource.xml
|  |  |  |  |  +--HibernateSessionFactory.xml
|  |  |  |  +--SpringBeans.xml
|  |  +--struts.properties
|  |  +--struts.xml
|  +--WebRoot/
|  |  +--jsp/
|  |  |  +--common/
|  |  |  +--layout/
|  |  +--WEB-INF/
|  |  |  +--classes/
|  |  |  +--lib/
|  |  |  +--tiles.xml
|  |  |  +--web.xml
```

EDIT:

After getting into more details and add detailed loggings I got one more thing in my logs.

```
2013-07-23 16:40:01,578 ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.error:38 - Unable to read class [com.abc.lab.actions.LoginAction] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Lorg/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor;I)V
```

And it's only one exception which I have mentioned here while it's giving the same exception with each action class available in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong. You should

- extend `struts-default` in your package, and
- add your interceptor to the default stack or to some other custom stack; right now, your whole stack is composed by only ONE interceptor, your.

Working configuration:

```xml
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
     <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="mylogging" 
                class="com.abc.lab.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor">
            </interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="loggingStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="mylogging" />

                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />    
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
</package>
```

You may want to include the namespace too in your package declaration, like

```xml
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
```

And if you want to use Spring DI to inject beans in your Actions, you need to put the following setting in `struts.xml`:

```xml
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
```

And please, do not use `chain` result: it is discouraged in the official documentation. It is highly likely that you have a better way to do what you want to achieve, for example with `redirectAction` result instead of `chain` result.